# Is it possible to filter Firebug's HTML panel?

Tags: html, firebug

Can I filter the *HTML* panel in Firebug? I have problems with additional HTML source code added by add-ons like Pearltrees.

Here's an example:

```
<span class="pearlItButton" style="position: absolute; display: none; cursor: pointer; z-index: 150000000; opacity: 0; width: 34px; height: 34px;" unselectable="on" id="pearlItButtonImg"></span>
<span class="pearlItButton" style="position: absolute; display: none; cursor: pointer; z-index: 150000000; opacity: 0; width: 34px; height: 34px;" unselectable="on" id="pearlItButtonTxt"></span>
<form target="pearltrees_overlay" action="https://www.pearltrees.com/s/pearler/listFromAddons" method="post" id="pearlIt">
  <input name="url" type="hidden"><input name="title" type="hidden">
  <input name="layout" type="hidden"><input name="text" type="hidden">
  <input name="buttonParams" type="hidden"><input name="version" value="0.9" type="hidden">
</form>
<span class="pearlItButton" style="position: absolute; display: none; cursor: pointer; z-index: 150000000; opacity: 0; width: 34px; height: 34px;" unselectable="on" id="pearlItButtonImg"></span>
<span class="pearlItButton" style="position: absolute; display: none; cursor: pointer; z-index: 150000000; opacity: 0; width: 34px; height: 34px;" unselectable="on" id="pearlItButtonTxt"></span>
<form target="pearltrees_overlay" action="https://www.pearltrees.com/s/pearler/listFromAddons" method="post" id="pearlIt">
  <input name="url" type="hidden"><input name="title" type="hidden">
  <input name="layout" type="hidden"><input name="text" type="hidden">
  <input name="buttonParams" type="hidden"><input name="version" value="0.9" type="hidden">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The elements within the tree and their attributes shown within the *HTML* panel basically **cannot** be filtered.

What can be filtered are HTML comments, which is done via the *HTML* panel's options menu.

Though, you can search for specific elements and attributes using the [search field](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Search_Field). That field not only allows you to search for full text but also to search using CSS selectors.

If you want to reduce the length of the lines, you can crop the attribute values to a specific length you can define via the preference `extensions.firebug.displayedAttributeValueLimit`, which can be changed within [`about:config`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/About:config). This will result in an output like this:

[image: Restricted attribute value length]

Furthermore, you can also delete the nodes you don't want to see by selecting them and pressing *Del* or via the context menu. Though this is altering the page, of course.

The last option is to temporarily disable the add-ons that add extra nodes to the page.

Comment: I want to filter out the code. I do not want to see him. AddOns like Pearltrees and Ghostery insert additional code.

Comment: I know, and I said that the *HTML* panel does not have an option at the moment (i.e. Firebug 2.0.x) to be filtered except comments and provided alternatives.